# including prebuilt libraries in android ndk

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk

After a great deal of pain, I have finally built UHD for android.  I use a script that takes a standard UHD package and builds everything with the android tools.  I then take the resulting libraries and include files and put them under the jni directory.  This is what my directory structure looks like

```
> jni
    > uhd
        - Android.mk
        > lib
            - libuhd.so
            - libuhd.so.003
            - libuhd.so.003.005
            > pkgconfig
                - uhd.pc
        > include
            - *.hpp
```

Here is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH      := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE            := uhd
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES        := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := lib/libuhd.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Everything build nicely when I include it in my project.  The problem comes in when I put it on the device.  The app immediately crashes.  Looking at the log file gives me the following message

```
E/dalvikvm(20135): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.myproject-1/libmyproject.so") failed: dlopen failed: could not load library "libuhd.so.003" needed by "libmyproject.so"; caused by library "libuhd.so.003" not found
```

So (no pun intended) I changed the LOCAL_SRC_FILES to be the libuhd.so.003, but android throws an error telling me that I am not allowed to do that.  A prebuilt shared library must end in .so, not .so.003.  I have also tried copying the library to the /libs folder in the base directory of the project, but that doesn't seem to work either.

How can I either change the library name or change what myproject.so is looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try calling (in Java) System.loadLibrary("libuhd.so")?

Comment: No I didn't.  I tried to include it in the Android.mk for the appropriate package.  That's how I was able to include the other many libraries that I link to.

Comment: That is only useful at link time.  Try calling System.loadLibrary("libuhd.so") before you attempt to use it to fix your runtime exception.